# Excel shortcuts not searchable in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, shortcuts, windows-search, windows-10-v1607

Our company now uses Windows 10 for all employee laptops.

I have many shortcuts in this folder

```
C:\Users\Dv_MH\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\
```

When I search with the name of the shortcut, all shortcuts to Internet Explorer or Chrome or Office Outlook work fine.

But Excel shortcuts present in that exact same folder never appear in the search results, in fact any excel shortcut in any folder never appear in any search result regardless where they are.

Even though, the actual excel files (not the shortcuts) appear in the search results pretty fine.

How can I fix that ? It's crucial in my work.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Haver you tried to search *.lnk files? A thing I usually do on an new PC is turn on suffixes. A lnk file is the shortcut prefix. Do you mean other shortcuts show up but Excel shortcuts don't? I've never noticed that.

Comment: @ejbytes Yep I am sure that .lnk files are indexed and I have added it myself and waited for re-indexing to occur. Yes other shortcut show up but Excel shortcuts don't. Please help.

Comment: Interesting. I tested your findings and find that I have not problem with this. I created a folder, inserted tools.xls, then created shortcut mytools to the tools.xls, performed a search for mytools and it appears fine. This works on my Win7 PC and my Win10 SP4.

Comment: AppData is a hidden folder. You shouldn't be creating shortcuts and placing them in here `C:\Users\Dv_MH\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\` Your Excel shortcuts should be placed in proper places such as the Desktop or in another folder localized away from system folders such as the one you are using. That's the problem.